# Most frequent string in cell array without respecting the alphabetical order

Tags: matlab, cell-array, mode

I want to find the most common string in a cell array but without respecting the alphabetical order.
Let me explain better with an example.

If I have this:

```
list = {'car', 'glasses', 'glasses', 'apple', 'apple'};
```

I want the answer to be **glasses** and not **apple** because **glasses** comes before **apple** in the array, even if **apple** is alphabetically less than **glasses**.

This method works but returns apple:

```
[unique_strings, ~, string_map] = unique(list);
mostComm = unique_strings(mode(string_map)); % -> apple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`'stable'` option with `unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to keep the order -

```
[unique_strings, ~, string_map] = unique(list,'stable');
unique_strings(mode(string_map))
```

From docs :

> [C,ia,ic] = unique(A,setOrder) and [C,ia,ic] =
>   unique(A,'rows',setOrder) return C in a specific order. setOrder can
>   be 'sorted' or 'stable':
>
> 'stable' — C is in the same order as A.

Sample run -

```
>> list
list = 
    'car'    'glasses'    'glasses'    'apple'    'apple'
>> [unique_strings, ~, string_map] = unique(list,'stable');
>> unique_strings(mode(string_map))
ans = 
    'glasses'
```